# SSIS C# scrip modification to get file created time in loop/list

Tags: c#, ssis

I"m using SSIS package with Script task to get files not older then `n` days and it's working fine, but now I need to bring into next step `CreatedTime` for each file.  Below I pasted the body of my script. It works partially I just can't pass  new var into `LastUpdated`.  Frankly don't know how to deal with this structure, can I add another dimension to  into existing list of create another list. I plan to use `User:LastUpdated` in the same way as FileNameArray.
Tx much !)

```
        DataTable NewList = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn("FileName");
        NewList.Columns.Add(col);
          DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("LastUpdated", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
          NewList.Columns.Add(col2); 

        foreach (string f in MyDirFiles)
        {
            finf = new System.IO.FileInfo(f);
            if (finf.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)  )        
                )
            {
               NewList.Rows.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f) , 
                                System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(f));        
            }
        }
        Dts.Variables["User::FileNameArray"].Value = NewList.Columns["FileName"];  //<--- need convert into object
        ////**Dts.Variables["User::LastUpdated"].Value = NewList(xxx);  


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code and comments - can conclude the following:

- `NewList2` variable has `DataTable` type (not present in code)
- `User:LastUpdated` SSIS package variable has `DateTime` type

In this case - you are trying to assign a complex structure (`DataTable`) to single value `DateTime` variable, which certainly raises an error. To do so, change type of `User:LastUpdated` to `Object`.

One can extend `NewList` table to contain both columns, like in the example below

```
DataTable NewList = new DataTable();
DataColumn col = new DataColumn("FileName");
NewList.Columns.Add(col);
DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("LastUpdated", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
NewList.Columns.Add(col2);
```

Adding a new row will be more awkward.

```
DataRow newRow = NewList.NewRow();
newRow["FileName"] = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f);
newRow["LastUpdated"] = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(f);
NewList.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Comment: Thanks F! I didn't add  `NewList2` Definition in my example,  as was not sure if this will work. I'm good with any solution which will work. Frankly just need help, bit short of C# guys around, I'm in dba. Tx much.

Comment: for this excerpt the only think I'm sure that `System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(f)` has right value, just need to ship it out of script in the same way like `FileNameArray`. Just tried to mimic current process with `FileNameArray`. Tx again. Will try to play with Object now.

Comment: @Mich28, please specify what do you want - receive CreationTime for each file or get the latest time or?

Comment: @Mich28, you will be better off adding one more column with **CreationTime** to `NewList` datatable. This will deliver table structure where each row contains file name and its creation time; otherwise you have to match two tables somehow.

Comment: Hi Ferdipux, I need to add `LastUpdated` value for each file, which should be paired with existing `FileNameArray`. As of now `FileNameArray` works OK, just need to add creation date.  Can you help to add new column to existing NewList and assign it to `LastUPdated`. I'm short of knowledge for this.

Comment: Thanks mucho  F!! I also updated my code,how to refer to given column at the end assignment ? `NewList["FileName"]`   (???)  this still show me an error ! Best M

Comment: And I changed inSSIS  FileName to Object

Comment: I Just need to find the way how to refer to the whole DataTable but only given column.

Comment: It's all clear now.Final step is to convert  `System.Data.DataColumn`  to Object Type to match SSIS Type.  I edited my script.Tx again F!!!